# managedCuda C# free GPU Memory

Tags: c#, cuda

I'm using C# with managedCuda lib.
I allocate Memory on the GPU with this command: 
  CudaDeviceVariable name = new CudaDeviceVariable(length);
and it works fine.
But I can not find the command to free it from the GPU.

thank you in advance =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `name.Dispose();` - `CudaDeviceVariable` is an `IDisposable`.

This also means you can use this handy syntax:

```
using (var name = new CudaDeviceVariable(length))
{
  // do the work
}
```

Comment: That's probably the best idea to use RAII.